# i don't want the picture to leave some space on the right side,i want the text to be in center,i want the picture to be responsive how can i doit?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCpOQ.png)please help me if you know thanks and if anyone have made an website for a restaurant before can you please send me the code. I want to use it as reference I will be very thankful to you it will help me a lot.

```
/* home section */

#home{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 3px 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

#home::before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url("../images/1.jpeg");
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1.4;
  
}

<section id="home">
 <h1 class="h-primary">Welcome to Half Dozen Shawarma</h1>
 <p class ="h-primary"> Lorem 14</p>
 <button class = "btn"> Menu </button>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking questions on bugs or when you're struck, you can't ask other developers to send whole code without trying something on your own... But since you're new, I'm gonna post a link which might help you... 
https://github.com/marynganga/Restaurant-Website-Template.
Good luck and happy learning...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

demo : https://codepen.io/shahemm/pen/YzrWvBv

Here you are :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="home">
 <h1 class="h-primary">Welcome to Half Dozen Shawarma</h1>
 <p class ="h-primary"> Lorem 14</p>
 <button class = "btn"> Menu </button>
</body>
</html>
```

css :

```
#home{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 3px 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}

  #home::before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1280/1080");
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 1.4;}
```

and to lean more visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Happy learning :)